# Glitchy Data Validation Custom Formula

Tags: google-sheets

```
=COUNTIF(IMPORTRANGE("[spreadsheet_id]", "$L:$L"), L2) <= 1
```

I'm using the above formula in my data validation rule to make sure all values are unique. The sheet referenced is a master list of different ranges combined (also using `IMPORTRANGE`) so I can check for uniqueness across multiple spreadsheets.

The formula is fine, but the validation does not work normally. I made sure I authorized access to the spreadsheet beforehand, but I've noticed some glitchy behavior. When I take that same formula and put it in a cell on the sheet and then resave the data validation rule, it somehow seems to get it working. But when I remove it again, it doesn't.

Is this normal behavior? Do I have to have a cell with the same formula on my sheet for it to work?

[image: Demo]